# Is it okay to use HTTP POST method with a query string, if a query string is used to find the resources that need to be updated?

Tags: rest, http, post

My HTTP API has a method that updates resources found by filter. Practically it is a POST method, that utilizes a query string **to find** desired resources and transfers data in its body **to update** found resources:

```
POST /module/resources?field_1=abc&field_2=def&field_n=xyz
body: {
    "desired_field":"desired_data"
}
```

I've heard it might be a code smell using a POST method and a query string together, but in the case presented above it seems perfectly reasonable to me.

Am I making wrong assumptions here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it okay to use HTTP POST method with a query string, if a query string is used to find the resources that need to be updated?

Yes.

> Am I making wrong assumptions here?

No.

The key ideas being that you, as the author of the resource, get to choose its identifier

> REST relies instead on the author choosing a resource identifier that best fits the nature of the concept being identified. -- [Fielding, 2000](https://www.ics.uci.edu/%7Efielding/pubs/dissertation/rest_arch_style.htm#sec_5_2_1_1)

the query is part of the resource identifier

> The query component contains non-hierarchical data that, along with data in the path component (Section 3.3), serves to identify a resource within the scope of the URI's scheme and naming authority  -- [RFC 3986](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc3986#section-3.4)

and that the semantics of HTTP methods are standardized across *all* resources

> Once defined, a standardized method ought to have the same semantics when applied to any resource, though each resource determines for itself whether those semantics are implemented or allowed. -- [RFC 7231](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7231#section-4.1)

Answer (score 1):

When talking about resources, there's from a HTTP/REST perspective no difference between:

```
/article/1
/article?id=1
```

So if you do a `GET` request on either of these to get the article, you can do a `PUT` or `PATCH` on either of those to make changes.

However, the way many developers think of query parameters and POST bodies is often 'just a different way to send parameters'. This is incorrect, because they have  a pretty distinct meaning, but using both at the same time *may* confuse some people.

So on a protocol level what you're doing is perfectly fine. I'd argue it's kind of elegant to use the URI as the locator and the body as the main message.